# Is O4I2 sufficient to reprogram cells (ie induce pluripotency)?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, development, stem-cells

Is exposure to the chemical [O4I2 (ethyl 2-((4-chlorophenyl)amino)-thiazole-4-carboxylate)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26143659) sufficient to reprogram an adult cell back to pluripotency?

They sell this chemical online for pretty cheap. My question is, if I wanted to start a colony of induced pluripotent stem (iPS) cells, would I only need to buy this or are other reprogramming materials required?

Answer (score 1):

No, the chemical [O4I2](https://www.caymanchem.com/product/19135) (thats a name, not a chemical formula btw) only helps to induce production of the [Oct-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oct-4) transcription factor. Even if just this chemical is sufficient to express Oct-4 (which it might not be, I'm not really sure about that), you still need to induce transcription of [other genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_pluripotent_stem_cell#Genes_used_to_produce_iPSCs) (usually Sox, cMyc & Klf4) to obtain iPS cells.